# Rails routes with dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, routes

So I have a weekly calendar view and I have a route set up to accept /:year/:month/:day for the start date.

```
  match "events/(:year/:month/:day)" => "events#index", 
      :constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/ },
      :as => "events_date"
```

I have two questions regarding the use of this route. First, when parsing the params, this is what I'm doing:

```
unless params[:year].nil? || params[:month].nil? || params[:day].nil?
  start_date = Date.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i)
end
start_date = start_date.nil? ? Date.today : start_date
```

This strikes me as pretty verbose and kind of ugly. Is there a better way?

And when making a link to another week in the calendar (for paging week to week), do I have to do something like

```
#assume an date object with the desired start date
link_to events_date_path(date.strftime('%Y'), date.strftime('%m'), date.strftime('%d'))
```

Which also seems kind of verbose and ugly. What's the best way to work with dates in routes?

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be human readable, and in that format? Would it make more sense to have it set up as match "events/(:date)" where :date ends up being like "2012-05-01" and you can do a direct strftime on that into a real date object?

Comment: No, this is a completely personal project, this is as much a programming exercise as it is a real problem

Comment: I suppose I'll take my answer to an actual answer field, then. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion would be to not use three separate variables. That way you don't end up with a lot of extra null checking and sanity checking in your controller. You could turn your match in to something look like this, with your constraints still in tact:

```
match "events/(:date)" => "events#index", 
      :constraints => { :date => /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/ },
      :as => "events_date"
```

Thus you would end up with something a little more sane in the controller:

```
unless params[:date]
  start_date = params[:date].strftime("%Y-%m-%d').to_date # assuming you want a Date
end
```

And I usually do those types of 'if this is set' checks something more like this, because I find it a bit more readable:

```
start_date = Date.today unless defined? start_date
```

You could even roll those last two together:

```
start_date = defined?(params[:date]) ? params[:date].strftime("%Y-%m-%d').to_date : Date.today
```

Comment: Note also that you could go directly to a date using this syntax: Date.strptime(params[:date], '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Point of interest, can you use forward slashes at part of the param itself without breaking the parts out into separate variables?

Comment: I'm not positive. My guess is yes, but I wouldn't recommend it because it's somewhat ambiguous. Your route would read "events/(:date)" and you're receiving "events/2012/05/01". To my mind that just feels a little dirty, since you're supposed to be splitting on /'s in a route.

Comment: So I started playing with this, and I ended up having to change the route to /events/week/(:date) because the original one was colliding with the default show RESTful route.